# Integrate and sync data of ZK time and attendance devices with web application

Tags: asp.net, sdk, synchronization, communication, time-and-attendance

I have web application which has employees information against their companies and hosted on web server.I want to manage attendance system using zktecho devices.So i have different questions as below

- So how i sync the attendance data of different terminals.
- Which sdk is best for this purpose?
- How i push the time attendance data to the
  remote server where web application is hosted

Comment: Did you manage to do this? I need help too

Comment: https://youtu.be/7CXILnRWjLE This is a cloud biometric software, check if this helps you

Answer (score 0):

Online SDK is restricted from the manufacturers as it may lead to the security issues. As it is online based, anyone can access the anyone's biometric device if the online SDK has been exposed. So it is kept as confidential by the manufacturers CAMS and ZKTeco. If you wnat you can use the 3rd part api services for the zk devices as documented at http://camsunit.com/application/zk-teco-essl-api-integration.html

Answer (score 0):

You could have a script to read the attendance logs from the terminals, append an identifier for each terminal and push them to the remote server.
From the server you will be able to know the terminal for each attendance record

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).